# Checking if AFP server is already mounted applescript

Tags: file, applescript, afp

How to I check if file server is currently connected? (Using AFP to connect) Sorry if Im asking this wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if a server is mounted there is a corresponding volume in `/Volumes`.

```
if "serverVolume" is in do shell script "ls /Volumes" then ... -- server is mounted
```

Replace `serverVolume` with the name of the volume.

Comment: How do I check if a new volume has been mounted. I can't use it your way, because the volume that is mounted depends on the username of the server.

Comment: Install an launchd agent to monitor the folder `/Volumes`. The agent can trigger an AppleScript.